# LLVM: Replacing all instances of an address with a constant

Tags: llvm

I'm trying to replace all instances of an address with a constant.

I'm getting & testing the address of store with the following (i is an instruction)

```
//already know it's a store instruction at this point
llvm::Value *addy = i->getOperand(0);
if(llvm::ConstantInt* c = dyn_cast<llvm:::ConstantInt>(addy)){
   //replace all uses of the address with the constant
   //operand(1) will be the address the const would be stored at
   i->getOperand(1)->replaceAllUsesWith(c);
}
```

I'd think this would work, but I'm getting the error that

```
"Assertion: New->getType()== getType() && replaceAllUses of value with new value of different type!" failed
```

and I'm not sure why...my understanding of replaceAllUses is that it would replace usage of address (i->getOperand(1) with the constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty straightforward: the type of the new value is not identical to the type of the old value that you are replacing.

LLVM IR is strongly typed, and as you can see in the [language reference](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html), every instruction has a specific type it expects as each operand. For example, `store` requires that the address's type will always be a pointer to the type of the value being stored.

As a result, whenever you replace the usage of a value, you must ensure first that they both have the same type - `replaceAllUsesWith` actually has an assert to verify it, as you can see, and you failed it. It's also simple to see why: operand 1 of a store instruction is always of some pointer type, and a `ConstantInt` always represents something of some integer type, so surely they can never match.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Perhaps you are thinking about replacing each `load` of that store's address with a usage of the constant? In that case, you'll have to find yourself all the `load`s that use that address, and for each of them (for each of the loads, I mean, not of the addresses) perform `replaceAllUsesWith` with the constant. There are standard LLVM passes that can do those things for you, by the way - check out [the pass list](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html). I'm guessing mem2reg followed by some constant propagation pass will take care of this.